# Kids living with grandparents on an old space ship that doesn't need to launch from a cradle

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Children's sci fi novel:

- space ship did not need to be launched from a cradle unlike the newer ships.
- children disappearing on school trip to uninhabited planet.
- Standing stones activated by music.
- It was a trading spaceship think the kids lived with grandparents and it was a really old ship

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they can help you remember anything else to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Hmm.. Dragonfall 5?

Comment: drgonfall 5 and the empty planet thank you soo much

Answer (score 3):

Per the comment by the OP above, this is *[Dragonfall Five and the Empty Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?912501)* (1973) by Brian Earnshaw.

Per the plot summary on [the Wikipedia article about the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfall_5):

> Tim and his brother Sanchez have to attend school on the Empty Planet,
> a place of musical rocks, whispering trees, from which the last
> inhabitants vanished without a trace.